# Binding .this to an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to get this "this" to work, to bind it to an/any HTML element that the function is applied to. I'm trying to keep it universal to make it possible to apply the same function to multiple HTML elements.

**Note:**

I don't want to mess with ids nor classes and such since I want to keep the function as universal as possible.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Old" onClick="Change(this);">

<script type="text/javascript">
function Change(){
     this.innerHTML = "New";
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your input tag is missing a closing angle bracket in your supplied example.

Comment: Sorry I just made a quick copy of the file, I apparently didn't catch the closing bracket. However it does exist, so it does not solve the issue.

Comment: you pass `this` as an argument to `Change` ... that doesn't bind anything, that passes an argument .. `function Change(element) { element.innerHTML = "New"; }` would work

Answer (score 2):

`innerHTML` won't work in this case. Being that this is an input, try using `value` instead.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('click', Change);
    
function Change(){
  this.value = "New";
  this.removeEventListener('click', Change);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Old" />
```

Comment: Glad to hear. Would you mind marking this as the correct answer then?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the page hits the `input` the `Change` function is not defined. Try the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function Change(){
     this.value = "New";
};
</script>

<input type="button" value="Old" onClick="Change.call(this);">

</body>
</html>
```

Note that I have changed the `input`'s `onClick` to `Change.call(this)`. And that the script is loaded before the control.

You can see a [working fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/JosephGarrone/vugt4prw/2/) Note that the JavaScript settings is configured so that the script is loaded in the head (Hit the cog in the JavaScript section).

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain why this has been downvoted? This is valid working answer.